# Renaming the files is renaming the extension of the file

Tags: c#

On My web site, I am letting the users upload the file and before saving the file on my server, I am renaming the file. If the user upload the file test.pdf, I want to rename the file test_123.pdf, but instead the file is renamed to test.pdf_123.pdf Below is my code:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile1 in UploadPDF.PostedFiles)
                        {
                            if (Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile1.FileName) == ".pdf")
                            {
                            
                                 UploadedFile = UploadPath + uploadedFile1.FileName;
                                 RenamedFile = UploadPath + uploadedFile1.FileName + "_" +  applicationID + ".pdf";
                                 File.Move(UploadedFile, RenamedFile);
                            
                            }
                        }
```

applicationID  is changing for every file.

With the above code, my renaming of the file is appended after the already existing file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the extension and take only the filename part before processing the change:

```
UploadedFile = UploadPath + uploadedFile1.FileName;
UploadedFileTemp = UploadPath + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uploadedFile1.FileName);
RenamedFile = UploadedFileTemp + "_" +  applicationID + ".pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because of `uploadedFile1.FileName`. Before uploading, just remove the extension. There is one Trim function that might be useful.

Take a look at this link: [.Net Trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming)

I think you can use `TrimEnd()` function to remove the extension.